# what is the best Serializable replacement for "Set" and "Collection" interfaces?

Tags: java

I have to serialize Collection and Set interfaces. Which are the best Serializable replacements for those interfaces on Java?

Comment: Are you looking for some thing like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314318/is-the-serialization-of-guava-immutable-collections-stable

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Set is an **Interface**.
Use HashSet that are **implementing** Set and HashSets **are serializable**.
Just be sure that all the objects in the Set is serializable.

For more info [Why java.util.Set is not Serializable?](http://www.coderanch.com/t/418100/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/Why-java-util-Set-not)

PS. It doesn't have to be a HashSet; use any **concrete** class that is serializable and implementing Set or Collection.

Comment: Well, I would say use whichever implementation is most appropriate for your requirements, rather than randomly recommending one with no background information.

Comment: I agree with that, the impotent thing is to choose an concrete class and not an interface.

Answer (score 2):

The type checking knows that set is not  serializable, but a subtype of set can be serializable.

Set is a Interface. But implementation of set is HashSet. This is serializable.

You would not expect to serialize a Set because a Set can not be instantiated.

```
Set st = new Set(); // illegal
```

So set doesn't really need to implement Serializable.

Anyway, you can use LinkedHashSet and TreeSet. Those are also  Serializable.

Answer (score 1):

Some common ones:

```
--HashSet:

All Implemented Interfaces:
    Serializable, Cloneable, Iterable<E>, Collection<E>, Set<E>

--TreeSet:

All Implemented Interfaces:
    Serializable, Cloneable, Iterable<E>, Collection<E>, NavigableSet<E>, 
    Set<E>, SortedSet<E> 

--ArrayList:

All Implemented Interfaces:
    Serializable, Cloneable, Iterable<E>, Collection<E>, List<E>, RandomAccess 

--LinkedList:

All Implemented Interfaces:
    Serializable, Cloneable, Iterable<E>, Collection<E>, List<E>, Queue<E>
```