# Create a Gson TypeAdapter for a Guava Range

Tags: serialization, range, gson, guava, rangeset

I am trying to serialize Guava Range objects to JSON using Gson, however the default serialization fails, and I'm unsure how to correctly implement a `TypeAdapter` for this generic type.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Range<Integer> range = Range.closed(10, 20);
String json = gson.toJson(range);
System.out.println(json);
Range<Integer> range2 = gson.fromJson(json, 
                            new TypeToken<Range<Integer>>(){}.getType());
System.out.println(range2);
assertEquals(range2, range);
```

This fails like so:

```
{"lowerBound":{"endpoint":10},"upperBound":{"endpoint":20}}
PASSED: typeTokenInterface
FAILED: range
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for
        com.google.common.collect.Cut<java.lang.Integer>. Register an
        InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$12.construct(
        ConstructorConstructor.java:210)
    ...
```

Note that the default serialization actually loses information - it fails to report whether the endpoints are open or closed.  I would prefer to see it serialized similar to its `toString()`, e.g. `[10‥20]` however simply calling `toString()` won't work with generic `Range` instances, as the elements of the range may not be primitives (Joda-Time `LocalDate` instances, for example).  For the same reason, implementing a custom `TypeAdapter` seems difficult, as we don't know how to deserialize the endpoints.

I've implemented most of a [`TypeAdaptorFactory`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) based on the template provided for `Multimap` which ought to work, but now I'm stuck on the generics.  Here's what I have so far:

```
public class RangeTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
  public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
    Type type = typeToken.getType();
    if (typeToken.getRawType() != Range.class
        || !(type instanceof ParameterizedType)) {
      return null;
    }

    Type elementType = ((ParameterizedType) type).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    TypeAdapter<?> elementAdapter = (TypeAdapter<?>)gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(elementType));
    // Bound mismatch: The generic method newRangeAdapter(TypeAdapter<E>) of type
    // GsonUtils.RangeTypeAdapterFactory is not applicable for the arguments
    // (TypeAdapter<capture#4-of ?>). The inferred type capture#4-of ? is not a valid
    // substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Comparable<?>>
    return (TypeAdapter<T>) newRangeAdapter(elementAdapter);
  }

  private <E extends Comparable<?>> TypeAdapter<Range<E>> newRangeAdapter(final TypeAdapter<E> elementAdapter) {
    return new TypeAdapter<Range<E>>() {
      @Override
      public void write(JsonWriter out, Range<E> value) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
          out.nullValue();
          return;
        }

        String repr = (value.lowerBoundType() == BoundType.CLOSED ? "[" : "(") +
                      (value.hasLowerBound() ? elementAdapter.toJson(value.lowerEndpoint()) : "-\u221e") +
                      '\u2025' +
                      (value.hasLowerBound() ? elementAdapter.toJson(value.upperEndpoint()) : "+\u221e") +
                      (value.upperBoundType() == BoundType.CLOSED ? "]" : ")");
        out.value(repr);
      }

      public Range<E> read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
          in.nextNull();
          return null;
        }

        String[] endpoints = in.nextString().split("\u2025");
        E lower = elementAdapter.fromJson(endpoints[0].substring(1));
        E upper = elementAdapter.fromJson(endpoints[1].substring(0,endpoints[1].length()-1));

        return Range.range(lower, endpoints[0].charAt(0) == '[' ? BoundType.CLOSED : BoundType.OPEN,
                           upper, endpoints[1].charAt(endpoints[1].length()-1) == '[' ? BoundType.CLOSED : BoundType.OPEN);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

However the `return (TypeAdapter<T>) newRangeAdapter(elementAdapter);` line has a compilation error and I'm now at a loss.

What's the best way to resolve this error?  Is there a better way to serialize `Range` objects that I'm missing?  What about if I want to serialize `RangeSet`s?

Rather frustrating that the Google utility library and Google serialization library seem to require so much glue to work together :(

Comment: I guess the problem is confusing `T` and `Range<T>`. Actually, I can't see the latter in your code, but `TypeAdapter<Range<T>>` is IMHO what the factory should return.

Comment: @maaartinus Yeah, the complicated generics is a big part of the problem.  `T` refers to the type to be processed by Gson (in this case, a `RangeSet<C>`) so the `TypeAdapter<T>` cast should be right, but in order to process a `RangeSet<C>` I need to be able to handle `C`s, which the `TypeAdaptor` doesn't really make accessible.  I was attempting to replicate the `Multiset` example in [`TypeAdaptorFactory`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) but I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: I see I was completely wrong. I guess your `elementAdapter` must be `TypeAdapter<E extends Comparable<E>>`, but I don't know if it's possible without a dirty hack. It's possible to cast anything to anything when casting first to `Object`. Sure, it's unsafe and dirty as hell, but sometimes it's the only way. Often I find a better solution after getting the hack working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels somewhat like reinventing the wheel, but it was a lot quicker to put together and test than the time spent trying to get Gson to behave, so at least presently I'll be using the following [`Converter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Converter.html)s to serialize `Range` and `RangeSet`*, rather than Gson.

```
/**
 * Converter between Range instances and Strings, essentially a custom serializer.
 * Ideally we'd let Gson or Guava do this for us, but presently this is cleaner.
 */
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Converter<Range<T>, String> rangeConverter(final Converter<T, String> elementConverter) {
  final String NEG_INFINITY = "-\u221e";
  final String POS_INFINITY = "+\u221e";
  final String DOTDOT = "\u2025";
  return new Converter<Range<T>, String>() {
    @Override
    protected String doForward(Range<T> range) {
      return (range.hasLowerBound() && range.lowerBoundType() == BoundType.CLOSED ? "[" : "(") +
             (range.hasLowerBound() ? elementConverter.convert(range.lowerEndpoint()) : NEG_INFINITY) +
             DOTDOT +
             (range.hasUpperBound() ? elementConverter.convert(range.upperEndpoint()) : POS_INFINITY) +
             (range.hasUpperBound() && range.upperBoundType() == BoundType.CLOSED ? "]" : ")");
    }

    @Override
    protected Range<T> doBackward(String range) {
      String[] endpoints = range.split(DOTDOT);

      Range<T> ret = Range.all();
      if(!endpoints[0].substring(1).equals(NEG_INFINITY)) {
        T lower = elementConverter.reverse().convert(endpoints[0].substring(1));
        ret = ret.intersection(Range.downTo(lower, endpoints[0].charAt(0) == '[' ? BoundType.CLOSED : BoundType.OPEN));
      }
      if(!endpoints[1].substring(0,endpoints[1].length()-1).equals(POS_INFINITY)) {
        T upper = elementConverter.reverse().convert(endpoints[1].substring(0,endpoints[1].length()-1));
        ret = ret.intersection(Range.upTo(upper, endpoints[1].charAt(endpoints[1].length()-1) == ']' ? BoundType.CLOSED : BoundType.OPEN));
      }
      return ret;
    }
  };
}

/**
 * Converter between RangeSet instances and Strings, essentially a custom serializer.
 * Ideally we'd let Gson or Guava do this for us, but presently this is cleaner.
 */
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Converter<RangeSet<T>, String> rangeSetConverter(final Converter<T, String> elementConverter) {
  return new Converter<RangeSet<T>, String>() {
    private final Converter<Range<T>, String> rangeConverter = rangeConverter(elementConverter);
    @Override
    protected String doForward(RangeSet<T> rs) {
      ArrayList<String> ls = new ArrayList<>();
      for(Range<T> range : rs.asRanges()) {
        ls.add(rangeConverter.convert(range));
      }
      return Joiner.on(", ").join(ls);
    }

    @Override
    protected RangeSet<T> doBackward(String rs) {
      Iterable<String> parts = Splitter.on(",").trimResults().split(rs);
      ImmutableRangeSet.Builder<T> build = ImmutableRangeSet.builder();
      for(String range : parts) {
        build.add(rangeConverter.reverse().convert(range));
      }
      return build.build();
    }
  };
}
```

*For inter-process communication, Java serialization would likely work just fine, as both classes implement `Serializable`.  However I'm serializing to disk for more permanent storage, meaning I need a format I can trust won't change over time.  Guava's serialization [doesn't provide that guarantee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8318152/113632).

Comment: If you wanted to stick with serialization, you could save your own type instead. I guess, a trivial class containing both bounds and their types would do. Personally, I'd trust the sentence "in reality, the serialized forms don't change very often", add a corresponding test, and be prepared to do the conversion.

Comment: That's fair.  I'd add that I also prefer my solution to Java serialization because it's human-readable, but admittedly that wouldn't be a deal-breaker for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Gson JsonSerializer and JsonDeserializer that generically supports a Range: https://github.com/jamespedwards42/Fava/wiki/Range-Marshaller

```
@Override
public JsonElement serialize(final Range src, final Type typeOfSrc, final JsonSerializationContext context) {
    final JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    if ( src.hasLowerBound() ) {
        jsonObject.add( "lowerBoundType", context.serialize( src.lowerBoundType() ) );
        jsonObject.add( "lowerBound", context.serialize( src.lowerEndpoint() ) );
    } else
        jsonObject.add( "lowerBoundType", context.serialize( BoundType.OPEN ) );

    if ( src.hasUpperBound() ) {
        jsonObject.add( "upperBoundType", context.serialize( src.upperBoundType() ) );
        jsonObject.add( "upperBound", context.serialize( src.upperEndpoint() ) );
    } else
        jsonObject.add( "upperBoundType", context.serialize( BoundType.OPEN ) );
    return jsonObject;
}

@Override
public Range<? extends Comparable<?>> deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type typeOfT, final JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    if ( !( typeOfT instanceof ParameterizedType ) )
        throw new IllegalStateException( "typeOfT must be a parameterized Range." );

    final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
    final JsonElement lowerBoundTypeJsonElement = jsonObject.get( "lowerBoundType" );
    final JsonElement upperBoundTypeJsonElement = jsonObject.get( "upperBoundType" );

    if ( lowerBoundTypeJsonElement == null || upperBoundTypeJsonElement == null )
        throw new IllegalStateException( "Range " + json
                + "was not serialized with this serializer!  The default serialization does not store the boundary types, therfore we can not deserialize." );

    final Type type = ( ( ParameterizedType ) typeOfT ).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

    final BoundType lowerBoundType = context.deserialize( lowerBoundTypeJsonElement, BoundType.class );
    final JsonElement lowerBoundJsonElement = jsonObject.get( "lowerBound" );
    final Comparable<?> lowerBound = lowerBoundJsonElement == null ? null : context.deserialize( lowerBoundJsonElement, type );

    final BoundType upperBoundType = context.deserialize( upperBoundTypeJsonElement, BoundType.class );
    final JsonElement upperBoundJsonElement = jsonObject.get( "upperBound" );
    final Comparable<?> upperBound = upperBoundJsonElement == null ? null : context.deserialize( upperBoundJsonElement, type );

    if ( lowerBound == null && upperBound != null )
        return Range.upTo( upperBound, upperBoundType );
    else if ( lowerBound != null && upperBound == null )
        return Range.downTo( lowerBound, lowerBoundType );
    else if ( lowerBound == null && upperBound == null )
        return Range.all();

    return Range.range( lowerBound, lowerBoundType, upperBound, upperBoundType );
}
```

Comment: Fabulous, thanks for sharing! I'll try this out when I have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straight forward solution. Works very well

```
import com.google.common.collect.BoundType;
import com.google.common.collect.Range;
import com.google.gson.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class GoogleRangeAdapter implements JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer {
    public static String TK_hasLowerBound = "hasLowerBound";
    public static String TK_hasUpperBound = "hasUpperBound";

    public static String TK_lowerBoundType = "lowerBoundType";
    public static String TK_upperBoundType = "upperBoundType";

    public static String TK_lowerBound = "lowerBound";
    public static String TK_upperBound = "upperBound";

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject)json;
        boolean hasLowerBound = jsonObject.get(TK_hasLowerBound).getAsBoolean();
        boolean hasUpperBound = jsonObject.get(TK_hasUpperBound).getAsBoolean();

        if (!hasLowerBound && !hasUpperBound) {
            return Range.all();
        }
        else if (!hasLowerBound && hasUpperBound){
            double upperBound = jsonObject.get(TK_upperBound).getAsDouble();
            BoundType upperBoundType = BoundType.valueOf(jsonObject.get(TK_upperBoundType).getAsString());
            if (upperBoundType == BoundType.OPEN)
                return Range.lessThan(upperBound);
            else
                return Range.atMost(upperBound);
        }
        else if (hasLowerBound && !hasUpperBound){
            double lowerBound = jsonObject.get(TK_lowerBound).getAsDouble();
            BoundType lowerBoundType = BoundType.valueOf(jsonObject.get(TK_lowerBoundType).getAsString());
            if (lowerBoundType == BoundType.OPEN)
                return Range.greaterThan(lowerBound);
            else
                return Range.atLeast(lowerBound);
        }
        else {
            double lowerBound = jsonObject.get(TK_lowerBound).getAsDouble();
            double upperBound = jsonObject.get(TK_upperBound).getAsDouble();
            BoundType upperBoundType = BoundType.valueOf(jsonObject.get(TK_upperBoundType).getAsString());
            BoundType lowerBoundType = BoundType.valueOf(jsonObject.get(TK_lowerBoundType).getAsString());
            if (lowerBoundType == BoundType.OPEN && upperBoundType == BoundType.OPEN)
                return Range.open(lowerBound, upperBound);
            else if (lowerBoundType == BoundType.OPEN && upperBoundType == BoundType.CLOSED)
                return Range.openClosed(lowerBound, upperBound);
            else if (lowerBoundType == BoundType.CLOSED && upperBoundType == BoundType.OPEN)
                return Range.closedOpen(lowerBound, upperBound);
            else
                return Range.closed(lowerBound, upperBound);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Object src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();

        Range<Double> range = (Range<Double>)src;
        boolean hasLowerBound = range.hasLowerBound();
        boolean hasUpperBound = range.hasUpperBound();

        jsonObject.addProperty(TK_hasLowerBound, hasLowerBound);
        jsonObject.addProperty(TK_hasUpperBound, hasUpperBound);

        if (hasLowerBound) {
            jsonObject.addProperty(TK_lowerBound, range.lowerEndpoint());
            jsonObject.addProperty(TK_lowerBoundType, range.lowerBoundType().name());
        }

        if (hasUpperBound) {
            jsonObject.addProperty(TK_upperBound, range.upperEndpoint());
            jsonObject.addProperty(TK_upperBoundType, range.upperBoundType().name());
        }

        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```